# inner html in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have an audio file and a javascript for it.

The javascript displays **percentage** of the audio buffered, if no buffered occurs it displays **loading...**

```js
function loop2() {
  var audio2 = document.getElementById("atwo1");
  var percentages = document.getElementsByClassName("atwo1l")
  var buffered = audio2.buffered;
  var loaded;

  if (buffered.length) {
    loaded = 100 * buffered.end(0) / audio2.duration;
    if (loaded.toFixed(2) != '0') {
      percentages[0].innerHTML = 'Loading: ' + loaded.toFixed(2) + '%';
    } else {
      percentages[0].innerHTML = 'Loading....';
    }
  }

  setTimeout(loop2, 50);
}

loop2();
```

```html
<audio id="atwo1" controls="controls">
  <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19gLpR7J8TVHmooVbM23eK5Xq0f9YXNZf">
</audio>
<p><span class="atwo1l"></span></p>
```

But for the above code, it does not displays `loading...`

When we place small audio file it will display. So why not for large files?

**Update:**

[Found a partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729073/inner-html-in-javascript-not-working#comment82418802_47729073) (**[updated codes](https://jsfiddle.net/6hco0wjh/11)**)

**[`Why a partial answer?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729073/inner-html-in-javascript-not-working#comment82432044_47729073)**

Comment: The code rendering ‘loaded’ is inside a conditional that only triggers if there is ‘buffered.lengfth’

Comment: @sideroxylon So I should have one more condition outside the function?

Comment: @sideroxylon And what would the condition be?

Comment: You should move into an ‘else’ on the outside conditional, as it won’t trigger on the inner conditional.

Comment: @JVOQ add an `else` to the outer `if`.

Comment: Not sure if the issue is with big files because the specific file in your code cannot be loaded at all by FF/Chrome/IE on *my* windows. So it never starts buffering.

Comment: Yes, it helped me thanks. Can we hide the audio till it is buffered for at least 1%? @sideroxylon

Comment: Like this:  ‘if (buffered.length) {
    loaded = 100 * buffered.end(0) / audio2.duration;
      percentages[0].innerHTML = 'Loading: ' + loaded.toFixed(2) + '%';
    } else {
      percentages[0].innerHTML = 'Loading....';
    }’

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli It is taking 5-10 minutes to start buffering. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729073/inner-html-in-javascript-not-working#comment82418850_47729073) is also a **why** question

Comment: @JVOQ in my case i get an error of failing to load because no decoder for requested format is available.

Comment: As for hiding, set its style to `display:none` and in your script inside the `if` make it `inline` again.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Maybe because of the URL. As it has Hindi (Indian Language) fonts.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli can I have the updated code for [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729073/inner-html-in-javascript-not-working#comment82418964_47729073) with reference to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hco0wjh/)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Any updates with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729073/inner-html-in-javascript-not-working#comment82418881_47729073)?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent('http://jainvidhya.epizy.com/Audio/Part1/ऑडियो नंबर 1 नमस्कार महामंत्र.mp4')`

Comment: @JVOQ see https://jsfiddle.net/6hco0wjh/2/ for the hide/show

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli The fiddle is working smooth. But when it is executed on the website, it is not working, on checking console it says  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffered' of null**. Go to `audio tutorials` --> `Part 1` --> `ऑडियो नंबर 1 नमस्कार महामंत्र` for the [Demo](http://jainvidhya.co.in/tindex.php)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Any updates?

Comment: @sideroxylon can you please help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729073/inner-html-in-javascript-not-working?noredirect=1#comment82432044_47729073)\

Comment: @AvrilAlejandro Can you please help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729073/inner-html-in-javascript-not-working?noredirect=1#comment82432044_47729073)

Comment: *you have to put the script block after the audio element*

Comment: added answer with all answers. What @AvrilAlejandro said is the correct way, but my answer solves it in another way (*more defensive*) that will handle the elements getting loaded dynamically at a later time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comments together in an answer

```
function loop2() {
  var audio2 = document.getElementById("aone1"),
      percentages = document.getElementsByClassName("aone1l"),
      buffered,
      loaded;

  if (audio2 && percentages) { // if both elements are found in the DOM
    buffered = audio2.buffered;

    if (buffered.length) {
      loaded = 100 * buffered.end(0) / audio2.duration;

      if (loaded.toFixed(2) != '0') {
        percentages[0].innerHTML = 'Loading: ' + loaded.toFixed(2) + '%';
      }

      if(loaded >= 1){
         audio2.classList.remove('un-buffered');
      }
    } else { // handle the case where the buffered.length is 0 or undefined
      percentages[0].innerHTML = 'Loading....';
    }
  }

  setTimeout(loop2, 50);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving your valuable time to me. I will update my codes with your code, meanwhile I request you please visit my [audio.php](http://jainvidhya.co.in/audio.php) and view-source it. Is that good having JavaScript's as I am having?(different for all audios) Or is there any way with a single script , which will work for all audios rather creating separate script all times? (Audios may increase or decrease). A request by a junior to a senior.

Comment: A request for helping me for the above comment

Comment: @JVOQ see https://pastebin.com/CMAxwsRG For code review though you can always visit the https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: trying your Pastebin, getting `Uncaught TypeError: audioElements.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @JVOQ my mistake. I am using jQuery so it should be `.each` instead of `.forEach`

Comment: Thanks, Sorry to disturb you. The last (but not least) question: I have updated the codes at [audio.php](http://jainvidhya.co.in/audio.php), working smooth. Now visit the `[site](http://jainvidhya.co.in) -> Audio Tutorials -> Part 2 -> ऑडियो नंबर 1 नमस्कार महामंत्र`. It will only show loading on starting and the audio will be hidden till it is buffered for 1%. (Good as expected). But the other audios (leaving first) are not hidden till they are buffered for 1%.

Comment: If it is troubling you I will ask the new question

Comment: @JVOQ you need to add the `un-buffered` class to all the `audio` elements.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that. Thank you so much for helping me. A new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779905/another-text-in-jquery-with-some-delay) raised by me with same codes but the different task in the hope you can understand my requirements and help me.